# Distilled water (pH 5.5 due to dissolved CO2) recommended for soil test - Do I need to adjust reading?

Tags: soil, ph, soil-test

All available sources recommend using distilled water for performing a soil pH test.

However, distilled water by itself is anywhere between pH 5.5 and 6.5 due to dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> (HCO<sub>3</sub><sup>-</sup> ions).

In my case, the distilled water is pH 5.5 according to my test strips.  When reading the *actual* soil pH is it necessary to reduce the reading by 1.5, or will I get a true reading without adjusting?

Comment: I'm going to suppose your test strips are not accurate enough to discern the difference due to ordinary room air levels of CO2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pH of distilled water makes no difference when being used to make a solution with ionizing materials. The quantity of ionic material in the distilled  water is negligible relative  to the total.